# Stata xtlogit, pa vs logistic

Tags: logistic, modeling, repeated-measures

I'm a grad student with a moderate statistics background having a bit of trouble figuring out which binary statistics model to use.

I have a dataset with repeated measures of patient lab values at various dates. Each patient experiences eventA only once in their lifetime. There are multiple dates of lab values captured before eventA and a single set of values at the date eventA occurs. I am developing a model to predict the outcome (eventA) using the lab value(s) as predictors.

Would this be considered repeated measures, even though eventA is once per lifetime & there are multiple measures of lab values for each patient? I have learned that for logistic regression one of the assumptions is that each observation must be independent from each other/not a repeated measure. If it doesn't satisfy this assumption, then do we have to use `xtlogit, pa`?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1502037-xtlogit-pa-vs-logistic Telling people about cross-posting is always courteous.

Comment: There is a statistical question here but in practice only Stata users can be expected to know what `xtlogit` does. For that reason, this question is better placed on Statalist.

Comment: @NickCox I tried to answer the statistics question here. I think I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If EventA can be considered the onset of a disease, so you are saying I should use Cox proportional hazards?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a survival analysis problem to me, particularly if you have some people who don't experience A during the time in the study (censoring). Survival analysis deals well with censoring. It can also deal with time varying covariates, which you have.